# How should I handle [xmlmapper] tag that relates to a different subject in most questions?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-disambiguation

The tag [xmlmapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xmlmapper) (72 questions) is defined as:

"XMLMapper is a third-party library for mapping XML to objects written in Swift" (most probably [this framework](https://github.com/gcharita/XMLMapper))

However, it seems that more questions that include this tag relate to the [Java XMLMapper class](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-dataformat-xml/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/xml/XmlMapper.html) of the [jackson-dataformat-xml](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml) extension component of the [Jackson JSON parser](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson).

To verify this, I performed a couple of searches based on tags:

Search: [[xmlmapper]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xmlmapper): **72** questions

Search: [[xmlmapper][java]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xmlmapper+java): **37** questions
Search: [[xmlmapper][jackson] -[java]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xmlmapper+jackson+-java): **7** questions

Search: [[xmlmapper][swift]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xmlmapper+swift): **12** questions
Search: [[xmlmapper][swift4] -[swift]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xmlmapper+swift4+-swift): **1** questions
Search: [[xmlmapper][swift5] -[swift]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xmlmapper+swift5+-swift): **1** questions

I think the most accurate search is the following (negating technologies of Java):
Search: [[xmlmapper] -[java] -[spring] -[jaxb] -[jackson] -[jackson-dataformat-xml] -[spring-boot] -[hibernate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xmlmapper+-java+-spring+-jaxb+-jackson+-jackson-dataformat-xml+-spring-boot+-hibernate): 24 questions (by reviewing them, I saw that 10 of them relate to neither Swift nor Jackson or Java at all) = **14** questions.

Based on the above, it seems clear to me that the xmlmapper tag is mostly used in questions referring to the jackson-dataformat-xml Java class (considering also that no other result appears in Google search results' first page when searching XmlMapper Java).

What should be the action for this tag?

A solution that comes to my mind is: Just change its definition and create another tag for the Swift framework (e.g., xmlmapper-swift-framework), then move the Swift-related questions there.
On the other side, XmlMapper on Java is just a class while swift xmlmapper is a framework.

Which approach should I follow?

Comment: Does XMLMapper do the same thing in both Java and Swift (ignoring that one is a class the other a framework)? If so then I'd suggest that the tag excerpt/wiki be updated to not be about a specific language version. IF they are different, then disambiguation seems like the better solution.

Comment: There already is a tag jackson-dataformat-xml, that should be used for all the jackson XML questions. We shouldn't have a tag per class, one per (extension) library is already enough. Retag and rename this one to swift-xmlmapper to disambiguate it I'd say.

Comment: @Gimby would it be a good practice to add a note in the swift-xmlmapper description that advices to use jackson-dataformat-xml for questions related to XmlMapper java class?